# /bin/sh, /bin/bash and /bin/dash all broken, how can I install them again

Tags: bash, dpkg, dash-shell

Removed all `/bin/sh`, `/bin/bash` and `/bin/dash`. I cannot install them because `dpkg` and `apt-get` need a shell to install and there is no shell available. I'm still logged in and my Ubuntu is still running. Is there a way to recover from this situation. By the way, I don't have a Live CD right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you currently have a working system:

1. **Download the packages.** Normally I'd suggest running `apt-get download bash dash` but if you have a browser, you can fish them manually from http://packages.ubuntu.com/ Just make sure you get the version for your distribution release and architecture.
2. **Extract the files you need and put them in the right place.** You might need to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> to run `pkexec nautilus` to get root access to write.

   `/bin/sh` is actually a symlink to `/bin/dash`. I'm not sure how this is managed (it's a "diversion", but I'm not sure by which package) so you might need to manually create the symlink. Again from <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>:

   ```
   pkexec ln -s /bin/dash /bin/sh
   ```

But I'd also download a LiveCD now while you're at it and get that burnt onto a USB stick. If you've forgotten anything you're going to need that when you reboot.

Answer (score 5):

Procedure for dash:

```
sudo apt-get download dash #download dash *.deb file
sudo dpkg-deb -x dash*.deb #extract deb file, a bin directory will be created
sudo cp ./bin/dash /bin/ #copy binary file to /bin directory
sudo ln -s /bin/dash /bin/sh #create a symbolic link from sh to dash
```

Now dash binary is recovered and everything should be OK, but to just to make sure, run this:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall dash
```

Same procedure for bash, but this time there is no need to create a symbolic link:

```
sudo apt-get download bash
sudo dpk-deb -x bash*.deb
sudo cp ./bin/bash /bin/
```

Just to make sure:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall bash
```